# Odd CheckedTextView Behavior

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, xamarin.android

Okay, bear with me this is a very odd & complex issue and I'm having a hard time explaining it.  I'm using Xamarin.Android (Monodroid) although the source of the issue is likely an android thing.

I have an Activity which pages through Fragments manually by adding and removing them.

```
next = Fragments[nextIndex];
FragmentTransaction ftx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
ftx.SetTransition (FragmentTransit.FragmentFade);

ftx.SetCustomAnimations (Resource.Animator.slide_in_right, Resource.Animator.slide_out_left);
ftx.Remove (CurrentFragment);
ftx.Add (Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, next, next.Tag);
ftx.Commit();
```

The Fragments have a LinearLayout, which is populated with Row Views at run-time.  (ListViews introduced too many focus issues with validating text entry).

```
// Manual ListView
this.Layout.RemoveAllViewsInLayout ();
for (int n = 0; n < Adapter.Count; n++)
{
    View view = Adapter.GetView(n,null,Layout);
    if (view != null) {
        if (view.Parent != Layout) {
            Layout.AddView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Some of these Row Views have within them a GridView.  (The gridview does not scroll)

```
TextView title = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.titleView);
GridView grid = view.FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gridView);
if (grid.Adapter == null) {
    InlineAdapter adapter = new InlineAdapter(view.Context, list, this.Adapter);
    // Set Grid's parameters
    grid.Adapter = adapter;
    grid.OnItemClickListener = adapter;
    grid.SetNumColumns(adapter.GetColumns(((Activity)view.Context).WindowManager));
    grid.StretchMode = StretchMode.StretchColumnWidth;
}
grid.ClearChoices();

// Get Current Value(s)
if (list.Mode == ListMode.SingleSelection)
{
    grid.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;

    for (int b = 0; b < list.Selections.AllItems.Count; b++)
    {
        grid.SetItemChecked(b, false);
    }
    grid.SetItemChecked(list.GetSelectedIndex(DataStore), true);
}
```

The grid views have in them CheckedTextViews (either single or multiple choice).

```
// From "InlineAdapter"
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    GridView grid = ((GridView)parent);

    int layout = (list.Mode == ListMode.MultiSelection) ? Resource.Layout.RowListInclusive : Resource.Layout.RowListExclusive;

    CheckedTextView view = (CheckedTextView)convertView;
    if (view == null)
    {
        view = (CheckedTextView)inflator.Inflate(layout, parent, false);
    }
    view.Text = items[position];

    // Calabash
    view.ContentDescription = list.ContentDescription + "." + Selections.ContentDescription(items [position]);

    return view;
}
```

When a fragment is presented the first time (before it is removed) everything performs as expected.

When a fragment is presented the second and subsequent times (after it is removed and re-added) only the last grid view accepts user input.  In addition, whatever is selected on this last grid view ALL of the grid views select. (e.g. if the last one selects choice 2, then all of the grid views change to selecting choice 2)

I have:

- Verified that the underlying data is correct
- Verified using `.GetHash()` that all of the CheckedTextViews, GridViews, and Adapters are unique for their given rows.
- Verified that touches propagate to the correct CheckedTextViews, and modify the correct data.
- Verified that `NotifyDataSetChanged()` is called for the correct GridView.

I am personally stumped to gump on this one.

Comment: The only thing I've found that seems to work is creating new Fragments every time I page to something... that's undesirable though, for performance and logical reasons.  If it's the only way, then sure.